# Can mixed survival models using coxme() incorporate competing risks?

Tags: r, survival, multilevel-analysis, competing-risks

I am running a two-level survival models with hospital admission over a 1-year period as the outcome. Age, and sex are individual level and unique to each person's id, and area socioeconomic status (area_ses) is unique to id_area.

Model here:

fit1 <- coxme(Surv(admit_endage, admit_binary) ~ age + sex + area_ses + (1|id_area), data_df)

However, individuals who die cannot be admitted to hospital and therefore I need to include competing risks. I have done so before using crr as found in this tutorial https://www.emilyzabor.com/tutorials/survival_analysis_in_r_tutorial.html#Part_3:_Competing_Risks. However, I cannot find any documentation to support use of competing risks using the coxme() package where the model is multilevel.

Is it possible to perform multilevel survival model with competing risks?